# Why is the dimension of my minkowski engine sparse tensor only 2 when the dimension of my coordinates is [4755,3]?

Tags: python

```
tensor([[ 4,  5, 15],
        [ 4,  5, 16],
        [ 4,  6, 13],
        ...,
        [27, 12, 15],
        [27, 12, 16],
        [27, 12, 17]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

this is my coordinates

`sparse_tensor = ME.SparseTensor(features=input_edge, coordinates=input_coords.int())`

this is how i initialise my sparse tensor

however when i run `print(sparse_tensor.D)` it returns 2

the tensor stride is [1,1]

i have been trying to figure out why the dimension of the sparse tensor is 2, by right it should be 3

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
A `MinkowskiEngine.SparseTensor` requires coordinates with batch indices, which means if the spatial dimension is *D*, the input coordinate of `SparseTensor` should be *D+1*.

The function `ME.utils.sparse_collate` will directly return the coordinates with batch indices.

Please refer to [Minkowski Engine 0.5.3 Documentation](https://nvidia.github.io/MinkowskiEngine/tutorial/sparse_tensor_basic.html) for more info.